# Is this a sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E \not = \emptyset$

Is the family of sets $A = \{ B \subset E: B \text{ finite or } B^{c} \text{ finite } \}$ a sigma-algebra on $E$?

I have concluded that $E, \emptyset \in A$ and that if $H \in A$ then $H^c \in A$.

But for the last part I have some troubles.

Assume $(H_j)j_{\in \mathbb{N}} \in A$

Then we have three possibilities

i) all $H_j$ finite hence the union is finite

ii) all $H_{j}$ infinte hence union infinte, but what about the complement , is it finite?

iii) $H_j$ can both be finite and infinte hence the union is infinite, but what about the complement, is it finite?

Comment: You may want to check claim (i). Can you write $\Bbb N$ as a union of countably infinitely many finite sets, perhaps even singletons?

Comment: By (i) do you mean: all $H_j$ finite hence the union is finte? Or the first properti of a sigma algebra $E, \emptyset$ ? @G.Sassatelli

Comment: Ok, you missed my point. Let's just say the claim (i) is false, and it's indeed the reason why the whole thing you are actually trying to prove is false. Can you see why?

Comment: Because we might have an infinte amount of $H_j$ which are all finite, but since there are infinitely many, the union might not be finite? @G.Sassatelli

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: And aswell we can not determine if the complement is finite? @G.Sassatelli

Comment: No. Indeed, you can find a countable family of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ whose union is neither finite nor of finite complement. Can you think of one?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $E$ is infinite. Then there is an injection $f \colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow E \colon n \mapsto e_n$. For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $\{e_n\} \in A$, as $\{e_n\}$ is finite. Suppose that $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then the infinite sets
$$
H_1 := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{e_{2n}\} \qquad \text{ and } \qquad H_2 := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{e_{2n+1}\} 
$$
would both lie in $A$. Because of 
$$
H_1^{\mathsf{c}} = E \setminus \bigg(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{e_{2n}\}\bigg) \supseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{e_{2n+1}\} 
$$
we see that $H_1^{\mathsf{c}}$ is also infinite. Hence both $H_1$ and $H_1^{\mathsf{c}}$ are infinite and thus $H_1 \notin A$. So $A$ cannot be a $\sigma$-algebra.

Especially if $E=\mathbb{N}$, one can consider the set of equal numbers $2\mathbb{N}$ and its complement $2\mathbb{N}_0+1$, the set of odd numbers. Both are infinite and thus are not in $A$. But we can write
$$
2\mathbb{N} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{2n\},
$$
where each $\{2n\} \in A$.